# How to change my chart control background color

Tags: c#, charts

This is my control:

```
        seriesTraffic = new Series();
        seriesTraffic.Color = Color.Black;
        seriesTraffic.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Spline;
        seriesTraffic.BorderWidth = 2;
        chart1.Series.Add(seriesTraffic);
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.White;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 10;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 10;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 10;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 10;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 5;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 1;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsStartedFromZero = true;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffsetType = DateTimeIntervalType.Number;

        var chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
        chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();

        chart1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        chartArea1.AxisY.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;

        chartArea1.AxisX.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
        chartArea1.AxisX2.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
        chartArea1.AxisX2.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;

        chartArea1.AxisX.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        chartArea1.AxisX2.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        chartArea1.AxisX2.LineWidth = 1;
        chartArea1.AxisX2.MinorGrid.Interval = 0.25D;
        chartArea1.AxisX2.MinorGrid.IntervalOffset = -0.01D;
        chartArea1.AxisX2.MinorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

        chartArea1.AxisY.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        chartArea1.AxisY.LineWidth = 1;
        chartArea1.AxisY.Maximum = 2D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MaximumAutoSize = 100F;
        chartArea1.AxisY.Minimum = -2D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MinorGrid.Interval = 0.25D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MinorGrid.IntervalOffset = -0.01D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MinorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

        chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
```

i want to change my control style to similar to this:

[image]

i try to change `BackSecondaryColor`, `BorderColor` but it has no effect.
i try to change `BackSecondaryColor`, `BorderColor` but it has no effect.
i try to change `BackSecondaryColor`, `BorderColor` but it has no effect.
i try to change `BackSecondaryColor`, `BorderColor` but it has no effect.

Answer (score 5):

To change the background color of the chart, you will need to change the `BackColor` property of the `ChartArea`.

```
chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].BackColor = Color.Black;
chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LawnGreen;
chart.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LawnGreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use something like this

```
var chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
var chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();

chart1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;               
chartArea1.AxisY.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
chartArea1.AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;

chartArea1.AxisX.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
chartArea1.AxisX2.Enabled = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.AxisEnabled.True;
chartArea1.AxisX2.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;

chartArea1.AxisX.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
chartArea1.AxisX2.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
chartArea1.AxisX2.LineWidth = 1;
chartArea1.AxisX2.MinorGrid.Interval = 0.25D;
chartArea1.AxisX2.MinorGrid.IntervalOffset = -0.01D;
chartArea1.AxisX2.MinorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

chartArea1.AxisY.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
chartArea1.AxisY.LineWidth = 1;
chartArea1.AxisY.Maximum = 2D;
chartArea1.AxisY.MaximumAutoSize = 100F;
chartArea1.AxisY.Minimum = -2D;           
chartArea1.AxisY.MinorGrid.Interval = 0.25D;
chartArea1.AxisY.MinorGrid.IntervalOffset = -0.01D;
chartArea1.AxisY.MinorGrid.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;          

chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
```

If the above does not work for you, I think that you should try to modify your control only in designer (using properties).
The background color is set by BackColor on your chart, you should also change the ChartArea BackColor to transparent.

Here a quick [example](https://app.box.com/s/wcb305ayaawifmlit336), hope it will help:)

Comment: See my update, i have added your code to mined and still same result